# Google directions API not working in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, api, google-maps, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Google API to lay a map from point A to point B in jupyter notebook using python. When I run the code of driving direction from the documentation( https://jupytergmaps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html ) it says ' you are not allowed to use google direction service'. I have enabled 'Geolocation', 'Driving Directions', 'Maps Javascript' through my account but still, I'm getting this error. I'm fairly new to this so its been difficult to figure out.

Comment: had you go through the [getting started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#GetStarted)  section of the api ? also it include `Effective July 16, 2018, a new pay-as-you-go pricing plan went into effect for Maps, Routes, and Places` so that probably the problem

Comment: are there any other ways through which I can get this ?

Comment: No, you need to set up a valid cloud project, valid key, enable billing, enable Directions API... Also please see https://jupyter-gmaps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authentication.html